# Why is ItoProcess failing here? (Stochastic Differential Equation)

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, random-process

Why is this code returning errors and failing to run? If I replace `Abs[x[t]]^2` with just `x[t]` it works perfectly.

```
proc = ItoProcess[{
    \[DifferentialD]x[t] == y[t] \[DifferentialD]t,
    \[DifferentialD]y[t] == -Abs[x[t]]^2 \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]W[t]},
   {x[t], y[t]},
   {{x, y}, {0, 1}},
   t,
   W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]
   ];
sim = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 20., 0.01}];
ListPlot[sim, Joined -> True]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ItoProcess is working as it should, given the model.

Comment: @Chris K: Maybe you can try it with a different MMA version like 11.3 to see if it fails with that version. Apparently, the OP has a problem with MMA.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I suspect they will run into problems with any version, since the deterministic part also diverges to $-\infty$ very fast (due to $dy/dt$ equation).  Try `sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -Abs[x[t]]^2, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}][[1]]` to see.

Comment: @Chris K: You are right. I get the following warning `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 6.42039120081436, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.` Singularity is encountered. The system has an identification problem, and this information can give hints to the OP to adjust the system.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around some more, I suppose it is something to do with the system tending towards negative infinity. If I only plot up to a time step of 5 (`RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]`) then the result looks like this

[image]